# Al almacenar datos en FireBase se cierra la activity y me devuelve a la activity principal

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy desarrollando un chat en Android Studio y tengo un problema, al almacenar un mensaje en firebase se cierra la activity de chat y me envía a la activity principal. Cuando ingreso nuevamente aparece el mensaje que envié pero envió un nuevo mensaje y pasa lo mismo. Quite la línea de código `databaseReference.push().setValue(new Msn(mensaje));` para poder saber si era error en la programación pero funciona correctamente (no se cierra la acivity).

Este es el código donde almaceno en la base de datos:

```
(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String mensaje = msn.getText().toString();
                databaseReference.push().setValue(new Msn(mensaje));
                msn.setText("");
            }
        });
```

este es el código donde llamo los mensajes de la base de datos:

```
databaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Msn m = dataSnapshot.getValue(Msn.class);
                adapter.addmsn(m);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda. gracias.

Comment: Lo mas importante en este caso es revisar el logcat y ver que error arroja

Comment: En el logcat aparece esto donde creo que me devuelve al inicio que se llama "inicioActivity": Logging event: origin=auto,name=screen_view(_vs),params=Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=EnviarmensajeActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=8985310933243045601, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=InicioActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=8985310933243045602}]

Comment: no aparece ningún error en el Logcat solo veo que aqui se activa la activity (firebase_screen_class(_sc)=InicioActivity, ).